# I want to print only department name

Tags: laravel-5

```
$dept_name = DB::table('departments')->select('dept_name')->where('id', '=', $request->alloted_dept)->get();
strong text**dd ($dept_name);
```

I want to print only department name but in browser it's showing
output:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => {#269 ▼
    +"dept_name": "IPS department"
  }
]
```

On echo $dept_name it outputs

```
ErrorException in abcController.php line 34: Array to string conversion
```

I want to  output only "IPS Department".

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop your results

```
$dept_name = DB::table('departments')->select('dept_name')->where('id', '=', $request->alloted_dept)->get();
```

#### Controller

```
foreach($dept_name as $name) {
   echo $name;
}
```

#### View

```
@foreach($dept_name as $name)
   {{ $name }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
$dept_name = DB::table('departments')->select('dept_name')->where('id', '=', $request->alloted_dept)->get();
$dept = "";
foreach($dept_name as $name) {
    $dept = $name->dept_name;
}
echo $dept;
```

Output:

```
IPS department
```

Thanks for answering Saravanan Sampathkumar